# Sequence of random variables and expected value

Tags: probability

Construct a sequence of random variables $ξ_n$ such that $ξ_n(ω) → 0$ for
every $ω$, but $Eξ_n →∞$ as $n→∞$.

My idea is as follows:

"Consider $$\xi_n= \begin{cases}
               n^2, & \mbox{ with probability } \dfrac{1}{n} \\
               0, & \mbox{ with probability } 1-\dfrac{1}{n}.
             \end{cases}$$
 $ \forall \epsilon >0$
\begin{eqnarray*}
  \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P(\vert \xi_n \vert \geq \epsilon) &=& \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P(\xi_n=n^2) \\
    &=& \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{1}{n}\\
    &=&0.
\end{eqnarray*}
Later $\xi \rightarrow 0$ in probability, but
\begin{eqnarray*}
  E \xi_n  &=& n^2* \dfrac{1}{n}+0*(1-\dfrac{1}{n})\\
   &=& n.
\end{eqnarray*}
so $E\xi_{n} \rightarrow \infty$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$."

Is ok the idea??

Comment: Is there a particular probability space of which $\omega$ must be a member? If so, what is it?

Comment: I do not know, but as the statement says, for every $ω$, In this case we are assuming A probability space $(\Omega, F, P)$ con $w \in \Omega$.

Comment: I assume that before the sentence that says "Construct a sequence ...," there is something that says $\omega$ is a symbol for any element of the probability space $\Omega.$ My question is, is anything said about $\Omega$ besides the fact that it is a probability space. If the answer to that question is "no," then you can choose whatever set you want to be $\Omega.$ If the answer is "yes," you should use that particular description of $\Omega$ in your answer.

Comment: Convergence in probability does not imply convergence on every elementary event. You need to construct a sequence which converges everywhere. It is not suffices to construct a sequence converging in probablilty.

Answer (score 2):

Your idea is mostly right, but isn't precise enough to definitely work. In order to be able to make a statement such as "$\xi_n(\omega) \to 0$ for every $\omega$", you need to say more about the specific way your sequence is realized over a specific probability space.

In this case, a natural way to do it is to say that the probability space $\Omega$ is the open interval $(0,1)$ (with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra and the Lebesgue probability measure), and define $$\xi_n(\omega) = \begin{cases} n^2 & \omega < \frac1n \\ 0 & \text{else}\end{cases}$$ for all $\omega \in (0,1)$. This has all the properties you described, and in addition, $\xi_n(\omega) \to 0$ for all $\omega$ because $\xi_n(\omega) = 0$ for all $n \ge \frac1{\omega}$.

To give you an idea of how sensitive the condition you want is: if we change the probability space to be the closed interval $[0,1]$, which is usually equivalent for most purposes, the condition no longer holds. When $\omega = 0$, $\xi_n(\omega) = n^2$ for all $n$, so $\xi_n(\omega) \to \infty$. Your proof shows that this can only happen on a set of measure $0$, but that's not the same as showing that it can never happen.

We can also realize your example over a discrete probability space. Let $\Omega = \{1,2,3,4,\dots\}$, with the $\sigma$-algebra $2^{\Omega}$, and $P$ defined by $P(\{k\}) = \frac{1}{k(k+1)}$. Now define $$\xi_n(\omega) = \begin{cases} n^2 & \omega \ge n \\ 0 & \text{else.}\end{cases}$$ You can check that $P(\xi_n = n^2)$ turns out to be $\frac1n$. As before, $\xi_n(\omega) \to 0$ for all $\omega$, because for any $\omega$ we eventually have $\xi_n(\omega)=0$.

Comment: Perhaps even more annoyingly than the $[0,1]$ vs $(0,1)$ stuff, one can note that if one chooses an **independent** sequence $(\xi_n)$ such that $P(\xi_n=n^2)=1/n=1-P(\xi_n=0)$, then $\xi_n(\omega)\to0$ does not happen for every $\omega$ since in fact, $P(\xi_n\to0)=0$.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much for your comments.